# Rails query subclasses and limit one each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an `artifacts` table that holds downloaded files. Each type holds different data.

```
class Artifact < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ForecastArtifact < Artifact
end

class ChargebackArtifact < Artifact
end

class CatalogArtifact < Artifact
end
```

For a single account, I am querying the MOST RECENT of each artifact type:

```
  artifact_types = Artifact.subclasses.map(&:to_s)

  artifacts_for_account = artifact_types.map do |type|
    @account.artifacts
            .where(type: type)
            .order("valid_as_of DESC")
            .limit(1).first
            .as_json({only: [:id, :account_id, :type]})
  end
```

unfortunately this does N queries.

Is there a single query you would do for this? a more rails-style of solving this problem?

Comment: Looks like its a problem with modeling the query and retrieving the data. Try to make the query work in your DB and then translate it to Rails/Active Record.

Comment: Can you please share your database structure

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PostgreSQL, you can use `DISTINCT ON` to solve this:

```
>> a = Account.last
  Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" ORDER BY "accounts"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Account id: 1, created_at: "2017-11-17 17:16:03", updated_at: "2017-11-17 17:16:03">

>> a.artifacts.select("distinct on (type) valid_as_of, type, id").group(:type, :valid_as_of, :id).order(:type, valid_as_of: :desc)
  Artifact Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  distinct on (type) valid_as_of, type, id FROM "artifacts" WHERE "artifacts"."account_id" = $1 GROUP BY "artifacts"."type", "artifacts"."valid_as_of", "artifacts"."id" ORDER BY "artifacts"."type" ASC, "artifacts"."valid_as_of" DESC LIMIT $2  [["account_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<ChargebackArtifact id: 22, type: "ChargebackArtifact", valid_as_of: "2017-11-17 17:06:03">, #<ForecastArtifact id: 21, type: "ForecastArtifact", valid_as_of: "2017-11-17 17:11:03">]>
```

This requires only one query for each account.